# change span width style using jquery data response

Tags: php, jquery

I want to change the width of span depends on load data from jquery respnse. Thanks.

```
<div class="star-rating">
     <span style="width:
         <script type='text/javascript'> 
             var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){ 
             $('#load_rating_average').load('get_average_rating.php?b_id=<?php echo $row['b_id']; ?>'); 
             },2000);
         </script>
         <span id=''></span>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any help guys Realy appreciate t

Comment: whats happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one Worked thanks for sharing.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
  var dt;
  $.get("get_average_rating.php?b_id=<?php echo $row['b_id']; ?>", function(data){
    dt=data;
    $("#load_rating_avg").css("width", dt +"%");
  });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery css for this, just get the value in javascript and assign it using jQuery

```
$("#spanId").css("width", "<?php echo $dynamicWidth ?>%"); // give id to span
```

or

```
$("#spanId").width("<?php echo $dynamicWidth ?>%");// give id to span
```

**EDIT**

you can use ajax request as well,

```
setInterval(function(){     
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_average_rating.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'b_id' : <?php echo $b_id ?> },
        success: function(width){ // assumed width = 75 (numeric o/p)
            // apply width to spanId
         $("#spanId").css("width",width + "%");
        }
    })
},2000);
```

Comment: did you get the `width` value in success? Any error in console ?